# Combine two result sets in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to combine 2 mysql select query into one result set

I've tried using Union and Union all but it gives me results not as expected

First Query : SELECT * FROM Users Order by AGE

```
NAME AGE
ABC 12
DEF 35
GHI 39
```

Second Query : SELECT * FROM Products Order by PRICE

```
NAME PRICE
ABC 11
DEF 23
GHI 25
```

I wanted the result to be

```
NAME AGE NAME PRICE
ABC 12 ABC 11
DEF 35 DEF 23
GHI 39 GHI 25
```

but when i used UNION the result was

```
NAME AGE
ABC 12
DEF 35
GHI 39
ABC 11
DEF 23
GHI 25
```

Comment: a join on name looks like what you want, but the data is weird with users and products sharing name values

Comment: it's just an example, which join should i use? let's imagine it's a code not a name

Comment: How are Users and Products related? Why are you putting them on the same row?

Comment: they are not related to each other, i want the tables to show side by side for another purpose

Comment: if they are not related, then you dont want a join. 2 queries or a union, and this is just a formatting issue, not a query one

Comment: SELECT NAME,AGE,NAME,PRICE FROM `Users`
LEFT JOIN `Products` ON `Users`.NAME = `Products`.NAME
UNION ALL
SELECT NAME,AGE,NAME,PRICE FROM `Users`
RIGHT JOIN `Products` ON `Users`.NAME = `Products`.NAME ORDER BY PRICE DESC

But it result around 111 rows while i have 6 rows only !

Comment: I did 2 query and union but it results combined in 2 columns instead of 4

Comment: the issue is not the querry(s) its how your processing the data afterwards, that you need to share.

Comment: I am combining the data to show them in one html table on a website
The table showed as
Quantity1,Price1 - Quantity2,Price2
i have 2 tables, tbl1 and tbl2
tbl1 have the first 2 variables (Quantity1,Price1)
tbl2 have the second 2 variables ( Quantity2,Price2)

Comment: Your `LEFT JOIN` should be enough. No need for `UNION ALL` and `RIGHT JOIN`. I assume that users table stores all user info and products table will only have data from any of the users.

Comment: It keeps giving back 55 rows because there is rows the same name with different age value or price value

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply join by the name. Check this out

```
SELECT u.NAME, u.AGE, p.NAME, p.PRICE
FROM Products p
INNER JOIN Users u ON p.NAME=u.NAME
```

Think of Union as just getting all your rows and putting into one big table.

---

Join is used to map row by row when considering two tables.

---

Also I have used aliases above to make the code more concise. 
An aliases is just a short name for the table. p instead of Products, o instead of orders.

Comment: It return 55 rows
while i have around 15 row in both tables

Comment: Are you sure about that? Can you do `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Products` and `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users ` and check?

Comment: products count 10
users count 8

Comment: USERS table? Because if you have multiple USERS with the same name this could be the result.

Comment: Yes users has the same name how to avoid duplicating result ?

Comment: Why are you using the user NAME in the `Product` table instead of a user ID?

Comment: Every Name has different Age value, i want to select by name not by ID

Comment: But your `products` table only have `Name` value. There's no unique relation between both table. If your `products` table have `Age` value, it's possible. But it would still be a problem if there are two or more value in `users` table that have the same `Name` and `Age`.

Comment: Is there is a way to combine the two result sets without any complications ?
something like
SELECT * FROM Users Order by AGE
UNION
SELECT * FROM Products Order by PRICE

but the result will be the 4 columns not 2 ?

Comment: your design is incorrect what I have mentioned is the simple way to do what your asking. But since you have completely mixed up your design by not having a unique identifier per user you get an incorrect result.
Each user has a unique age BUT! there is no unique name for each age. In other words there is no way to uniquely identify a row in your users table.

Answer (score 0):

As both queries aren't related use PHP to handle the output:

```
$users = $conn->query('SELECT Name,AGE FROM Users Order by AGE');
$products = $conn->query('SELECT Code,Price FROM Products Order by Price');
do {
  $u = $users->fetch();
  // handle empty case
  // else write user row data
  $p = $products->fetch();
  // handle empty case
  // else write product row data
} while (/* both not empty condition */);
```

Comment: This is the method i am thinking about,
I tried
$users = $conn->query('SELECT Name,AGE FROM Users Order by AGE');
$products = $conn->query('SELECT Code,Price FROM Products Order by Price');
$statement = $connection->prepare($users);
  $statement->execute();
  $result = $statement->fetchAll();
$statement1 = $connection->prepare($products);
  $statement1->execute();
  $result1 = $statement1->fetchAll();

then 
foreach ($result as $row) :
foreach ($result1 as $row1) :
echo escape($row["NAME"]);
echo escape($row1["NAME"]);
endforeach;
endforeach;

2 foreach array not working

Comment: think about what a nested loop actually is, which is why I've written one single loop. Fill in the gaps, I find PHP and web to be quite ghastly.